# Lubuntu 20.04- How to make power button to suspend OR add a suspend keybinding?

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, power-management

Power management settings on Lubuntu 20.04 have no option for power key behavior. Is there a config file where I could set either a shortcut for suspend or remap power button from shutdown to suspend?

Comment: Shortcut keys are covered in the manual (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.14/shortcut_keys.html) however I've done no testing using a power-button in running a suspend command..  (*I don't have time to test it either currently*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the command `systemctl suspend -i` to a hotkey to set up a hotkey to suspend the system. This will work on any desktop environment .

If Lubuntu does expose a pre-defined action for this in its Global Action Manager dialog, then, of course, you can define a hotkey there or change the existing hotkey.